# Subset pandas data frame based on & operation with columns from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different data sets. Based on a condition from `column values in these 2 data frames` I want to create a new data set.

```
d1=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[57,58,59,68,61],'Period':['Day_3','Day_4','Day_5','Day_3','Day_2'],'pay':[1000,3000,2000,1000,5000]})
d2=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[68,58,59,42],'Period':['Day_1','Day_8','Day_9','Day_6'],'pay':[10000,30000,20000,10000]})
```

`d1` and                                      `d2`

```
    ID  Period  pay                        ID   Period  pay 

0   57  Day_3   1000                   0   68   Day_1   10000
1   58  Day_4   3000                   1   58   Day_8   30000
2   59  Day_5   2000                   2   59   Day_9   20000
3   68  Day_3   1000                   3   42   Day_6   10000
4   61  Day_2   5000
```

`temp` would be the subset if these conditions hold true
`temp=d1[d1.ID.isin(d2.ID) & d1['Period']<=d2['Period']]`

`d1[d1.ID.isin(d2.ID)` gives partial result whereas `d1['Period']<=d2['Period']]` this throws an error
`ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects` I extracted numbers from days,and stored the values as day_numbers columns and executed the above code and I get the same error.

I need the result to be,

```
   ID   Period  pay
0  58   Day_4   3000
1  59   Day_5   2000

How to get this result?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on column `ID`  and create a boolean `mask` by comparing the numerical part of `Period`, then use this mask to filter the rows:

```
df = d1.merge(d2[['ID', 'Period']], on='ID', suffixes=['', '_r'])
mask = (
    df['Period'].str.split('_').str[-1].astype(int) <=
    df['Period_r'].str.split('_').str[-1].astype(int)
)
df = df[mask].drop('Period_r', 1)
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   ID Period   pay
0  58  Day_4  3000
1  59  Day_5  2000
```

Comment: Period <= Period_r string compare  ?

Comment: `'Day_4'>'Day_10'`

Comment: Now it is better ~